# How to remove equally spaced elements from an array with length of 'n' to match a given length 'y'?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, algorithm

Let's say I have array `foo` and a positive integer `y`, where `foo.length` > `y`.
I want to remove elements from `foo` so that `foo.length` becomes `y` (or very close to it).

Also, I need to preserve the first and last element of `foo`.  The indices of the removed elements must be spaced apart as equally as possible.  `Foo` can be sliced, or it can be used to create a new array.

Example: if `foo` = `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,1,2,3,4,5]` and `y` = `6`, then `trimmedfoo` could be `[a,c,e,g,2,4,5]` or maybe `[a,c,e,2,4,5]`, but not `[a,c,e,g,2,4]` because the last element of `foo` is missing.

Pseudocode solutions are fine, although as3 is my language of choice. :)

Thanks!

Comment: I understand difference between `1` and `3` is 2. Difference between `f` an `g` is 1. What's the difference between `g` and `1`?

Comment: I'm confused on what you are trying to accomplish, your first sentence is confusing how can foo.length > y and also foo.length == y....

Comment: Collin - foo.length becomes == y after removing elements from foo. That is the question. How many elements do I need to remove, and at what interval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a string of length `n`, and you want it to be length `m`.  You have `n-2` elements to pick from, and `m-2` elements to pick for your new array.  Now, suppose you have currently picked `i` elements and have passed `j` elements.  If `i/j` < `(m-2)/(n-2)` then you are behind.  You probably ought to take another element.  What you really want to know, for a maximally even selection, is whether `(i+1)/(j+1)` or `i/(j+1)` is closer to your target of `(m-2)/(n-2)`.  If overflow isn't a problem, you can do a little algebra to figure out that this is equivalent to whether `(i+1)*(n-2) - (j+1)*(m-2)` is more or less than `(n-2)/2`; more means `i` is better (so don't take this one), while less means `i+1` is better.

I'm not familiar with ActionScript, but here's some Scala that hopefully can work as pseudocode:

```
// Don't worry about the [T: ClassManifest] thing
// that just means it can work on arrays of any type

def pare[T: ClassManifest](a: Array[T], m: Int) = {
  val b = new Array[T](m)
  val n2 = a.length - 2
  val m2 = m - 2
  b(0) = a(0)
  var i,j = 0
  while (j < n2) {
    val diff = (i+1)*n2 - (j+1)*m2
    if (diff < n2/2) {
      i += 1
      j += 1
      b(i) = a(j)
   }
   else j += 1
  }
  b(m2+1) = a(n2+1)
  b    // This means "return b"
}
```

Let's try it out!

```
scala> pare(Array[Any]('a','b','c','d','e','f','g',1,2,3,4,5),6)   
res1: Array[Any] = Array(a, c, e, 1, 3, 5)

scala> pare(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),4)
res2: Array[Int] = Array(1, 4, 7, 9)

scala> pare(('a' to 'z').toArray, 16)
res3: Array[Char] = Array(a, b, d, f, h, i, k, m, n, p, r, t, u, w, y, z)
```

As you can see, this gives very even spacings.

Comment: slick! it would be nice also the other way round ; to expand an array with respect to a pattern. thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Yup, same logic, except you copy from the short one to the long one every time, not just when the short one advances.

Comment: Wow, you nailed it! Worked swimmingly on a 2188 element array squished down to 720.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. But could you explain, where the `(n-2) / 2` comes from? What sense it has to compare the difference with the half of the initial length? Or it's just a result of the formula transformation?

Comment: @mortalis - The `n-2` comes from the requirement that the first and last elements are kept.  The exact formula comes from algebraic manipulation of the inequalities.

Answer (score 3):

I have translated Rex Kerr's awesome algorithm to PHP and wanted to post it here since I think it will be easier for others to read. The only real difference is this returns the array untouched if it is smaller than the desired amount:

```
private function evenlyReduceArray($originalArray, $desiredCount){

    if(count($originalArray) <= $desiredCount)
    {
        return $originalArray;
    }

    $newArray             = array();
    $trimmedLength        = count($originalArray) - 2;
    $trimmedDesiredCount  = $desiredCount - 2;

    $newArray[0] = $originalArray[0];

    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    while($j < $trimmedLength)
    {
        $diff = ($i + 1) * $trimmedLength - ($j + 1) * $trimmedDesiredCount;
        if($diff < $trimmedLength / 2)
        {
            $i += 1;
            $j += 1;
            $newArray[$i] = $originalArray[$j];
        }
        else{
            $j+= 1;
        }
    }

    $newArray[$trimmedDesiredCount + 1] = $originalArray[$trimmedLength + 1];

    return $newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

subtract the value of y from the length of foo.
divide the length of foo with the subtraction result - and lets call the result N.
now copy the array to new array and jump over without copying every N'th element.
make sure to start jumping over elements only from the second element and to stop before the last one (If the last N'th count is the last element just jump over the one before).

in the above example:
foo.length = 12, y=6, N= 12-6=6, foo.length / N = 2

so we go over and move every second element.

in other example we may need to jump over few more element to fix the result array of the division have remainder

Answer (score 1):

Tested against your values, and others, and works.

```
var originalArray:Array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','1','2','3','4','5'];
var newLength:Number = 6;

var trimmedArray:Array = originalArray.filter(function(item:*, i:int, a:Array):Boolean {
    return  (((i + 1) % (a.length/newLength)) == 1) || (i == 0) || (i == a.length - 1);
});

trace(trimmedArray); // outputs a,c,e,g,2,4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first and last elements are the only untouchable elements in the array wouldn't the easier method be remove the second and second-last items repeatedly until you reach your required length?

```
foo = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,1,2,3,4,5];
y = 6;
loopType = 1;

while(foo.length>y)
{
    if(loopType==1)
    {
        foo[1].splice(1,1); //remove second item
        loopType = 2; //set loop to remove from other end of array
    }
    else
    {
        foo[1].splice(foo.length-2,1); //remove second-last item (foo.length-1 is the last item)
        loopType = 1; //set loop to remove from other end of array
    }
}
```

Now foo should be [a,e,f,g,1,5];

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it completely ignores the 'equally spaced' portion of the requirement.  I'm dealing with arrays with 1000's of elements, so chopping off a few dozen on each side of the array is going to make things a bit lopsided.

Imagine you had a very dense dotted line.  If you squint, it appears to be a solid line.  Now say you remove every third dot.  If you squint harder, it still looks like a solid line.  However, if you remove a big chunk of adjascent dots, then it looks like you have two lines.

My problem is not graphical in nature, but hopefully this illustrates what I am after.