# Eliminate Items From Array To Reach Fixed Length - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, canvas, geometry

I am trying to write a JavaScript function that removes items from an array to reach a defined length. The function should eliminate the "gaps" evenly through the array. I need this function to simplify polygon vertices for canvas drawing.

This is how it should work:

[image]

This is the code I came up with:

```js
function simplify(array, vertices) {

  // Calculate gap size
  var gap = array.length - vertices;
  gap = Math.floor(array.length / gap);

  var count = 0;
  var result = [];

  // Fill a new array
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (count == gap) {
      count = 0;
    } else {
      result.push(array[i]);
      count++;
    }
  }

  // Eliminate 1 item in the middle if length is odd
  if (result.length > vertices) {
    result.splice(Math.floor(result.length / 2), 1);
  }
  return result;
}

// This gives the wrong result depending on the length of the input!
// The result should be an array with the length of 3
console.log(simplify([
  { x: 10, y: 20 },
  { x: 30, y: 40 },
  { x: 40, y: 50 },
  { x: 50, y: 60 }
], 3))
```

However, this only seems to work sometimes and the problem may be in the math. What's the algorithm that can achieve this or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you know that your code only works sometimes, you should provide an example where it does not work ... I changed your code to a snippet and running a small example it works fine

Comment: The only issue that I could think of from looking at your code: `if (result.length > vertices) {` you already know there could be a case where the results could be different than the vertices but you are only taking one out... what if the difference is greater than one? why not put an exit in the for loop once you meet the amount of vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in the same way I do nearest-neighbor texture lookups. The floating point step variable (greater than zero) is floored to the next lower index, but when 'floor(i*step)' is greater than 'i' it takes it's first jump.

```
   function simplify(array, vertices){

      vertices = vertices || 1;///No div by zeros please :)

      var result = [];

      var step = array.length/vertices;

      for(var i=0;i<vertices;i++){
         result.push(array[Math.floor(step*i)]);
      }

      return result;

   }


//Testing it out
   var testarr = [];

   for(var ai=0;ai<51;ai++){
      testarr[ai] = {
         x:ai,
         y:10*ai
      }
   }

   console.log(testarr.slice(0));

   var ret = simplify(testarr, 29);

   console.log(ret.slice(0));
```

Incidentally,

```
   function simplify_bilinear(array, vertices){

      var result = [];

      var step = array.length/vertices;

      for(var i=0;i<vertices;i++){
         var fistep = Math.floor(i*step);//The nearest neighbor index
         var current = array[fistep];//This element
         var next = array[fistep+1];//The next element
         var mix = (i*step)-fistep;//The fractional ratio between them. As this approaches 1, the mix approaches the next value.
         //mix = mix * mix * (3 - 2 * mix);//Optional (s-curve) easing between the positions. Better than linear, anyway.
         //Alternately to the above//mix = Math.sin((mix*2 - 1)*Math.PI)*.5+.5;///for a sinusoid curve
         //True Bezier would be optimal here but beyond this scope 
         var mixed_point = {
            x:current.x+(next.x-current.x)*mix,//basic mixing, ala 'mix' in your average math library
            y:current.y+(next.y-current.y)*mix,
         }
         result.push(mixed_point);
      }

      return result;

   }
```

is a bilinear mag-filter, if you would ever like to up the count instead of lowering it. This could branch if the desired-length('vertices') is greater than the 'array.length'. Also a useful algorithm for software audio synth.

Comment: This creates your own values ... it does not preserves the existing values

Comment: @Helder Sepulveda, The first block directly answers the OP's question. Only the bilinear filter (the second code block) creates new values. In addition, the OP's code produces a new array, not an in-place array modification.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I just tested it and it works perfectly and as intended. Also creating a new array is not a problem, as my original attempt did that too. If the old array needs to be updated, it can just be replaced with the result.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250285/how-to-remove-equally-spaced-elements-from-an-array-with-length-of-n-to-match)

Suppose you have a string of length n, and you want it to be length m. You have n-2 elements to pick from, and m-2 elements to pick for your new array. Now, suppose you have currently picked i elements and have passed j elements. If i/j < (m-2)/(n-2) then you are behind. You probably ought to take another element. What you really want to know, for a maximally even selection, is whether (i+1)/(j+1) or i/(j+1) is closer to your target of (m-2)/(n-2). If overflow isn't a problem, you can do a little algebra to figure out that this is equivalent to whether (i+1)*(n-2) - (j+1)*(m-2) is more or less than (n-2)/2; more means i is better (so don't take this one), while less means i+1 is better.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to eliminate items to cut that array to a desired length. Use the Array.splice() function.

So if your `desiredLength = 3` for example. And you have an `array = [1,2,3,4,5]`.

`array.splice(0,desiredLength).length == desiredLength` should be true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would be an easy solution. However, it just cuts away the end, making it not practical for this use case (simplifying polygon vertices).